# How does tuple unpacking differ from normal assignment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

From [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html) I learnt that

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object

But when I tried to give some example for my session and I found out that it behaves differently with assignment and tuple unpacking.

Here is the snippet:

```
>>> a,b = 300,300
>>> a is b
True
>>> c = 300
>>> d = 300
>>> c is d
False
```

Comment: It's not defined how `is` behaves for integers. Any knowledge you gain about how one implementation behaves today will be fragile.

Comment: @Anonymous: "Implementation-defined" is more accurate than "not defined", but the statement about fragility still holds

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird Integer Cache inside Python 2.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/weird-integer-cache-inside-python-2-6). Not exactly the same question but the accepted answer (disclaimer: mine) shows what happens in the case of tuples which I believe it's enough to answer your question: it's the so-called peephole optimizer that avoid duplicating constants.

Comment: Thank you @Bakuriu, found some interesting explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because int is immutable, Python may or may not use exists object, if you save the following code in to a script file, and run it, it will output two True.

```
a, b = 300, 300
print a is b

c = 300
d = 300
print c is d
```

When Python compile the code, it may reuse all the constants. Becasue you input your code in a python session, the codes are compiled line by line, Python can't reuse all the constants as one object.

The document only says that there will be only one instance for -5 to 256, but doesn't define the behavior of others. For immutable types, `is` and `is not` is not important, because you can't modify them.

Comment: You can simulate this on the interpreter prompt by putting all your code in a single function and then running it (as opposed to running them one at a time).

Answer (score 2):

```
 import dis

 def testMethod1():
     a, b = 300, 300

 print dis.dis(testMethod1)
```

Prints:

> 4           0 LOAD_CONST               2 ((300, 300))
>                 3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
>                 6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
>                 9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
>                12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>                15 RETURN_VALUE             None

```
 def testMethod2():
     a = 300
     b = 300
```

Prints:

> 7           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (300) 
>                 3 STORE_FAST               0 (a) 
>     8           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (300) 
>                 9 STORE_FAST               1 (b) 
>                12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
>                15 RETURN_VALUE             None

So, it looks essentially the same, but with `LOAD_CONST` in one step in the first method and two steps in the second method....

**EDIT**
After some testing, I discovered that both methods return `False` eventually; however, on one run only, ie not putting the methods in a loop, they seem to always return `True`.  Sometimes it uses a single reference, and sometimes it does not.

The documentation only states that -5 to 256 will return the same reference; hence, you simply just shouldn't be using `is` for comparison (in this case) as the number's current `id` has no guarantee on it.

NB: You never want to use `is` for comparison of values, as that's not what it's for, it's to compare identities.  My point was that `is`'s return value is not always going to be `True` when you're outside of the defined range.

Comment: Hi Steve P, I tested in osx, python 2.7.2

Comment: It is up to the Python implementation. Loading in two steps gives more time to free low level cache memory. The cache [-5, 256] happens in Python code, but imutable objects (like int) can be reused. You can't trust these caches.

Comment: Apropos your last paragraph, `is` is not to be used for "comparison". `is` should be used for "identity". Comparing a and b is like saying "is a equal to b". Testing identity is like saying "are a and b the same thing"

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I understand what `is` does.  What I'm saying is that you don't want to be using `is` for the sake of comparison (in this case).