# Mysterious Cases of Booleans, Equivalencies, and Object Identifiers

Tags: python, boolean, logic, python-3.4, truthiness

**First Mystery of Strings:**
How come `bool('foo')` returns `True`?

> if 
>   `'foo' == True` returns `False`
>   `'foo' == False` returns `False`
>   `'foo' is True` returns `False`
>   `'foo' is False` returns `False`

**Second Mystery of Integers**: 
How come `bool(5)` returns `True`?

> if 
>   `5 == True` returns `False`
>   `5 == False` returns `False`
>   `5 is True` returns `False`
>   `5 is False` returns `False`

**Third Mystery of Zeros**: 
How come `bool(0)` returns `False`?

> if 
>   `0 == True` returns `False`
>   `0 == False` returns `True` <-- **Special Case** 
>   `0 is True` returns `False`
>   `0 is False` returns `False`

I am aware of some of the truthiness of Python, however, this all seems a bit mysterious. Someone mind shedding some light on this?

Comment: [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to read this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

```
'foo' == True  # -> False
'' == True     # -> False
'' == False    # -> False
```

will always be `False`. a string does not equal a `bool`. but - yes - `bool('non-empty-str') -> True`; `bool('') -> False`.

and so on for you other 'mysteries'.

`is` compares the identities `id()` of two objects (there are some mysteries here as well: [What's with the Integer Cache inside Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/weird-integer-cache-inside-python-2-6))

also this may be interesting: [Is False == 0 and True == 1 in Python an implementation detail or is it guaranteed by the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-in-python-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guarante)

Answer (score 2):

It is because both `0` and `''` are `False` in Python, while non-empty strings and non-zero Integers are True.

In all of your examples the reason they are returning otherwise from your expectations is because `==` checks for the same `value` while `is` checks if the two point to the same object.

So in the first case, `foo` is `True`, but they are not the same value. As well, `foo` is not pointing to the same value as `True` which is why it returns false. The same pattern continues for the rest of the examples.