# python built-in integer object

Tags: python

I read an article that python retains some number objects for better performance. For example:

```
x = 3
y = 3
print(id(x))
print(id(y))
```

gives out same values, which means that x and y are referencing to exactly same object. The article suggested that the retained number objects are approximately in range 1~100.

So I tested following code for getting the exact range:

```
for i in range(-1000,1000):
    x = int(str(i))
    y = int(str(i))
    if str(id(x)) == str(id(y)):
        print(i)
```

and the result is quite weird: it prints out -5~256.
I'm wondering how these two magic numbers came from and why they're being used. Also, will these two values change in different environment?
Thanks!

Comment: It's a CPython implementation detail (optimization), not Python in general.

Comment: the answer is, don't use ids for non mutable types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

256 is a power of two and small enough that people would be using numbers to that range.

-5 I am less sure about, perhaps as special values?

Related: [What's with the Integer Cache inside Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/weird-integer-cache-inside-python)

Also a word of wisdom from that thread:

> this is an implementation detail, don't ever rely on it happening or not happening