# What is the difference between destructured assignment and "normal" assignment?

Tags: python

I was playing around in the python 2.7.6 REPL and came across this behavior.

```
>>> x = -10
>>> y = -10
>>> x is y
False
>>> x, y = [-10, -10]
>>> x is y
True
```

It seems that destructured assignment returns the same reference for equivalent values. Why is this?

Comment: Huh. And if you use positive integers (`x=10`; `y=10`) you see different behavior.

Comment: `is` checks the memory address of the object...so why would you expect two variables to share the same address like you've done?

Comment: Any two variables that are assigned to values between -5 and 256 (including -5 and 256) would have the same ids.

Comment: It's not the assignment so much as the list literal is reusing the same object. Try `z = [-20, -20]; z[0] is z[1]`.

Comment: @Akavall Elaborate?

Comment: This might also help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-inside-python/15172182#15172182

Comment: @Dark, your first link is differentiating between small numbers and lists or tuples of small numbers.

Comment: @EvanRose The first links answer did cover this portion, so I thought of it as dupe. But the second link is much better to answer this case.

Comment: I might be missing it, but where does that first link use destructured assignment?

Comment: @chepner Your explanation makes sense to me. The interpreter uses the same object for repeating values in a list to save memory.

Comment: This behaviour is different in `python3.x`.  You will get both of them as `False`.

Comment: Python 2 is dead, so don't worry about it. Version 3 behaves as expected.

Comment: Related ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: @gecko As something that is almost certainly an implementation-dependent optimization, I wouldn't depend on any consistent behavior even in Python 2.

Comment: More importantly, why are you testing integers for identity?

Comment: Just for curiosity and educational purposes.

Comment: @gecko The OP posted about this behavior  [here](http://9tabs.com/random/2017/12/23/evil-coding-incantations.html)

Comment: @chepner you are right, but I think you wanted to write "python 3" instead of "python 2"

Comment: @miracle173 I was referring to gecko's implication that the behavior is specific to a version of Python. It isn't; whether two literals will refer to the same object in memory or not is not defined by the language; it is an implementation-dependent optimization. The only time you can rely on two names to refer to the same object is if you explicitly assign one to the other: `x = y` guarantees that `x is y` will subsequently be true (assuming neither name is modified in between).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know nothing about Python but I was curious.

First, this happens when assigning an array too:

```
x = [-10,-10]
x[0] is x[1]  # True
```

It also happens with strings, which are immutable.

```
x = ['foo', 'foo']
x[0] is x[1]  # True
```

Disassembly of the first function:

```
         0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-10)
         3 LOAD_CONST               1 (-10)
         6 BUILD_LIST               2
         9 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
```

The `LOAD_CONST (consti)` op pushes constant `co_consts[consti]` onto the stack. But both ops here have `consti=1`, so the same object is being pushed to the stack twice. If the numbers in the array were different, it would disassemble to this:

```
         0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-10)
         3 LOAD_CONST               2 (-20)
         6 BUILD_LIST               2
         9 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
```

Here, constants of index 1 and 2 are pushed.

`co_consts` is a tuple of constants used by a Python script. Evidently literals with the same value are only stored once.

As for why 'normal' assignment works - you're using the REPL so I assume each line is compiled seperately. If you put

```
x = -10
y = -10
print(x is y)
```

into a test script, you'll get `True`. So normal assignment and destructured assignment both work the same in this regard :)

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you disassembled the Python code? I've never seen that before, it looks really useful.

Comment: @Shuklaswag - import dis; dis.dis(func)

Answer (score 6):

What happens is that the interactive Python interpreter compiles *every statement separately*. Compilation not only produces bytecode, it also produces *constants*, for any built-in immutable type, including integers. Those constants are stored with the code object as the `co_consts` attribute.

Your `x = -10` is compiled separately from the `y = -10` assignment, and you end up with entirely separate `co_consts` structures. Your `x, y = [-10, -10]` iterable assignment on the other hand, is a single assignment statement, passed to the compiler all at once, so the compiler can re-use constants.

You can put simple statements (like assignments) on a single line with a semicolon between them, at which point, in Python 2.7, you get the same `-10` object again:

```
>>> x = -10; y = -10
>>> x is y
True
```

Here we compiled a single statement again, so the compiler can decide it that it only needs a single object to represent the `-10` value:

```
>>> compile('x = -10; y = -10', '', 'single').co_consts
(-10, None)
```

`'single'` is the compilation mode the interactive interpreter uses. The compiled bytecode loads the `-10` value from those constants.

You'd get the same thing if you put everything in a function, compiled as a single compound statement:

```
>>> def foo():
...     x = -10
...     y = -10
...     return x is y
...
>>> foo()
True
>>> foo.__code__.co_consts
(None, -10)
```

Modules are also compiled in one pass, so globals in a module can share constants.

All this is an *implementation detail*. You should **never, ever** count on this.

For example, in Python 3.6, the unary minus operator is handled separately (rather than `-10` being seen as a single integer literal), and the `-10` value is reached after constant folding during the peephole optimisation. This gets you get two separate `-10` values:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> compile('x = -10; y = -10', '', 'single').co_consts
(10, None, -10, -10)
```

Other Python implementations (PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc.) are free to handle constants differently again.