# Array slicing seems like it's making a deep copy?

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Slicing in python is supposed to make a shallow copy. However, when I run the following:

```
cur = [[0] * (2) for _ in xrange(2)]
cur2 = [row[:] for row in cur]
cur2[0][0] = "foo"
print(cur)
print(cur2)
```

I get:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0]] # cur
[['foo', 0], [0, 0]] # cur2
```

which makes it seem like it's a deep copy.

I have two questions:
1) What's happening here? Is this a deep or shallow copy?
2) What about this syntax makes it so much faster than copy.deepcopy? For example, is it something with the way python manages memory?

Comment: What do you think those slices are making copies *of*?

Comment: I'm not sure: A deep copy of each row?

Comment: Why do you think it's a *deep* copy of each row? Would you see different results from a shallow copy of each row?

Comment: A shallow copy of `cur` would be `cur2 = cur[:]`. You performed a deep copy by going inside `cur` and copying each row.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes - if it was a shallow copy, "foo" would be in cur. Modifying cur2 would also modify cur.

Comment: @khelwood Then how come this is so much slower than copy.deepcopy?

Comment: @user2009020 because the `deepcopy` function is much more involved than this, and it can't make these assumptions, because it works *for objects generically*

Comment: @user2009020 also note, these are not arrays, they are `list` objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Would you mind explaining the difference? I always thought lists were the same as arrays in Python - seems I'm mistaken.

Comment: @user2009020 they are not. When you say `array` in Python, that usually means a `numpy.ndarray` object, or even an `array.array` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making *shallow copies* of the inner lists (i.e. the rows), which is effectively the same as a deep copy of the outer list if the inner lists are just lists of `int` objects.

You've essentially implemented a deep copy function for the special case of a list of lists of integers.

Using `copy.deepcopy` will be slower because that function will have to investigate and cache all id's of the objects, including the `int` objects. Your snippet isn't doing that, but in this particular case, it doesn't matter (note, small `int` objects are cached at the interpreter level, they are essentially singletons, and anyway, `int` objects are immutable so they don't really have to be copied at all).

Here's a [link to the `copy` module source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/copy.py) if you eant to see exactly what is involved in a generic deep-copy.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I follow about the part about the int objects - what does caching the IDs of the objects accomplish? And what do you mean by caching at the interpreter level (and at what level are normal objects cached)?

Comment: @user2009020 small `int` objects ranging from `-2` to `256` are cached by the CPython implementation (that is what I mean by the interpreter level). Read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-inside-python). The `copy` module creates its own cache using a `dict` in Python. In any event you would never have to copy `int` objects anyway, because they are immutable. But again, `copy.deepcopy` doesn't know in advance anything about the `object` it is copying, so it checks for objects it's already seen, to avoid a cycle.

Comment: So am I right to say that copy.deepcopy is slower because it copies each int object, whereas the code in my question doesn't?

Comment: @user2009020 no, it doesn't copy each `int` object, for immutable objects, `__deepcopy_atomic` is simply `return x`. However, *it checks every object* and still caches the id.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what a shallow and a deep copy is.

A shallow copy copies the structure of a collection (essentially the memory locations), whereas a deep copy duplicates everything (as in the actual data) in memory.

What you are doing here is forming a new list of copies of each of the sub-lists from the original 2d list - thus resulting in an entirely new list with *no ties to the original list* - therefore you have done a *deep copy*.

If, instead, you were to do: `cur[:]`, you would just be copying the outer list that contains the same references to the inner list - therefore a *shallow copy*.

In your case, as all the memory locations are different, changing one element does not effect the original, but if you were to just do `cur[:]`, then the inner rows would reference the same locations in memory, so changing elements from either list would effect the other list.