# Equality Operator Producing True For 2 different Objects in Memory

Tags: python, equality

Why does my equality method produce **True** when the 2 objects ***point*** and ***b*** point to 2 different objects in memory?

```
import math


def main():

    point = Point(2, 3)

    print(point == Point(2, 3))

    b = Point(2, 3)

    print(id(point), id(b))


class Point:

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y

    def distance_from_origin(self):
         return math.hypot(self.x, self.y)

    def __eq__(self, other):
         return id(self.x) == id(other.x) and id(self.y) == id(other.y)

    def __repr__(self):
         return f"Point({self.x!r}, {self.y!r})"

    def __str__(self):
         return f"{self.x!r}, {self.y!r}"
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

Comment: Use `is` to check if they point to the same object. Where exactly do you compare `point` and `b`?

Comment: @Ares The \_\_eq\_\_ method is for implementing custom comparing methods

Comment: In main(), line # 2. My understanding is that since id() produces 2 different locations in memory, these should not be equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` of `Point` objects are different, because they're different objects and there is no cache/interning mechanism for them (which would be wrong because they're mutable).

`==` works because when invoking `==` on  `Point`, you call `__eq__` and it's coded like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
     return id(self.x) == id(other.x) and id(self.y) == id(other.y)
```

so, it's *wrong*, but it works most of the time because of interning of integers from -5 to 256 in CPython (further tests show that it works with bigger values but it's not guaranteed). Counter example:

```
a = 912
b = 2345

point = Point(a, b)

print(point == Point(456*2, b))
```

you'll get `False` even if `456*2 == 912`

Rewrite as this so you won't have surprises with big integers:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
     return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

If you remove this `__eq__` method, you'll get `False`, as in that case, Python default `==` operator on an unknown object only has object identity to perform comparisons.

But the purpose of `==` is to compare object *contents*, not *ids*. Coding an equality method that tests identities can lead to surprises, as shown above.

In Python when people use `==`, they expect objects to be equal if values are equal. Identities are an implementation detail, just forget about it.

(Previous versions of Python require you do define `__ne__` as well, as it's not automatically the inverse of `__eq__` and can lead to strange bugs)

**In a nutshell**: don't use `is` (besides `is None` idiom) or `id` unless you're writing a very complex low-level program with caching and weird stuff or when debugging your program.

Comment: I still get True when I use self.x == other.x. Aren't self and other 2 different objects? If they are, then shouldn't "==" produce True only when self is compared to self?

Comment: the idea of `==` is to compare against _values_. What you're describing is `is`

Answer (score 0):

Python caches small integers (in range [-5, 256]), thus `id(self.x) == id(other.x) and id(self.y) == id(other.y)` is `True`. Since `self.x` and `other.x` are the same objects in memory. Find a different way of comparing those two objects or get rid of your custom `__eq__` and use the default way (Python will return `False` for `point == Point(2, 3)` in that case).
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172182/10147399) answer for more on the issue.