# When iterating through a list inside of a function, why is 0 not 0.0?

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I am trying to solve a problem in which I have to remove the zeroes (both `0` and `0.0`) from a list and add them to the end of the list (the zero that is appended can be a `0`, doesn't have to be `0.0`). But the catch is that I must not remove `False`. I thought I finally figured out my problem by using `is` instead of `==` but for some reason it's not working:

```
arr = [9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]
def move_zeros(array):
    temp = array.copy()
    j = 0
    for p, i in enumerate(array):
        if i is 0 or i is 0.0:
            del temp[p - j]
            j += 1
            temp.append(0)
    return temp

print(move_zeros(arr))
```

I've tried putting parentheses at the `if` statement but the result is the same. It removes all the `0` but for some reason it won't remove `0.0`. Result:

```
[9, 0.0, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0.0, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I rewrote the function but outside of the function and for some reason it works:

```
array = [1, 0, 2, False, 0.0, 4]
for p, i in enumerate(array):
    if i is 0 or i is 0.0:
        del temp[p - j]
        j += 1
        temp.append(0)
```

And here the result is how I would expect it:

```
[1, 2, False, 4, 0, 0]
```

Why is the floating point zero being removed when executed outside of the function, but when the function `move_zeros` is called, the floating points are not recognized in the `if` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only handle `floats` and `ints` - so you can construct a new list from your input if the value is not 0:

```
arr = [9,0.0,0,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]

def move_zeros(array):
    len_arr = len(array)
    return ([ x for x in array if x != 0.0]+[0]*len_arr)[:len_arr]

# equivalent non-listcomprehension but simple for loop
def m_z(arr):
    k = []
    tmp = []
    for e in arr:
        if e/1.0 != 0.0:
            k.append(e)
        else:
            tmp.append(0)
    return k+tmp

    print(move_zeros(arr))
```

Output:

```
[9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If `x` is an integer  only `0` and `-0` can lead to `0.0`  - if `x` is a float, only `0.0` and `-0.0` can lead to 0.0 - simply do not put them into the output. `.copy()` is not needed because the list comprehension copies already for you.

The check for intergers and `is` works because python caches integers from -5 to 256 or so - they all get the same `id()` and hence `is` "seems" to work.

Only use `is` for `None` checks or if you know what you do, never for numbers.

If you want to leave non (`ìnt,float`) untouched you can check for that too:

```
arr = [9,0.0,0,False,9,1,2,0,1,0,1,0.0,3,0,1,9,0,0,0,0,9]

def move_zeros(array):
    len_arr = len(array)
    return ([ x for x in array if type(x) not in {int,float} or 
             x != 0.0]+[0]*len_arr)[:len_arr]

# [9, False, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

Read more:

- [What's with the Integer Cache inside Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-inside-python)
- [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)
- [thruthyness: why `False is 0` - Part 1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
- [why `False is 0` - Part 2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values)

---

Small sanity check:

```
k = 365
i = 365 // 5 * 5  # if you do i = 365 only, they are ==/is True, this way: they are not

for elem in [0,False,k]:
    for olem in [0,False,i]:     
        print(f"{str(elem):>8} is {str(olem):<10}:   {str(elem is olem):<10} ")
        print(f"{str(elem):>8} == {str(olem):<10}:   {str(elem == olem):<10} ")
```

Output:

```
       0 is 0         :   True       
       0 == 0         :   True       
       0 is False     :   False      
       0 == False     :   True       
       0 is 365       :   False      
       0 == 365       :   False      
   False is 0         :   False      
   False == 0         :   True       
   False is False     :   True       
   False == False     :   True       
   False is 365       :   False      
   False == 365       :   False      
     365 is 0         :   False      
     365 == 0         :   False      
     365 is False     :   False      
     365 == False     :   False      
     365 is 365       :   False      # k is i
     365 == 365       :   True       # k == i
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! But could you point out in the question why is the `if` statement inside of the function not recognizing `0.0` and outside of it (in the second example) it is recognizing it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the division by `1.0`?

Comment: Yes, of course. But why bother dividing by `1.0` at all? It makes no difference to the returned result, and just makes the code more confusing. Your solution would work just fine without the divisions. That is, `x / 1.0 != 0.0` could be replaced with `x != 0.0` with no change in behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

use `==`, not `is`. `is` is for comparing identity (two "things" occupying the same space in memory, essentially), `==` is for equality (do two things have the same defining properties). Furthermore, with floats it is often useful to check whether things are "close enough", e.g. 
`is_equal = a-b < 0.00001`

Comment: Also, in CPython, at least, small ints are cached, floats are not, which explains why `0 is 0` can be (but isn't required to be) true.

Comment: OP states they used `is` to avoid catching `False` in the function, `False==0.0` evaluates to True

Comment: I understand I can put a check before the `if` statement that checks if the element is `False` and do what you said with `==`. The thing I don't understand is the behavour inside and outside the function.