# Unexpected output with "is" keyword

Tags: python

I am unable to figure out the output of the following program

```
big_num_1   = 1000
big_num_2   = 1000
small_num_1 = 1
small_num_2 = 1
big_num_1 is big_num_2 # False
small_num_1 is small_num_2 # True
```

What is happening above?
Why is one False and other True.

Source: https://luminousmen.com/post/python-interview-questions-senior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `is` compares the *identity* of two objects (that is, if they're exactly the same object.) You want to test for *equality*, and for that you must use the `==` operator:

```
big_num_1 == big_num_2
=> True

small_num_1 == small_num_2
=> True
```

In case you're wondering why this example worked:

```
small_num_1 is small_num_2
=> True
```

It's because Python [caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-inside-python) small (between -5 and 256) `int` objects internally, so the objects used in the comparison were taken from the cache and were the same. `big_num_1` and `big_num_2` are greater than 256, so they're represented by two different objects, and the identity test fails.