# a = 1000, b = 1000. Why does `a is b` return true when run from command line, but not in an interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers), we know that Python returns a reference to integers from -5 <= x <= 256. 
When I enter the following into an interpreter, I get the expected results:

```
big_num_1 = 1000
big_num_2 = 1000
print(big_num_1 == big_num_2, big_num_1 is big_num_2)
```

Which gives me:

```
True False
```

But if i save it inside the file `myFile` and simply do an import:

```
import myFile
```

It always give me the following output:

```
True True
```

Does Python handle these references differently when not run from an interpreter?

Comment: It is very much up to the interpreter and the optimisation process which numbers will be interned and which won't be. You simply should never use `is` with numbers, because there's no right answer.

Comment: @deceze my be your comment with extra example can be the answer?

Comment: @Paul Thats about the same as the answer the OP himself  linked to - we would need a canonical for int interning which I was unable to locate - there are plenty of posts about string interning though - but they do not quite fit this question. This is essentially a "why" - "because it is like that and implementation detail based" question that has not really a good answer. *Don't us is to compare ints* is the best answer

Comment: @BearBrown probably because interning is an implementation detail that "just is" and there are a bazillion posts that do tell you not to use **is** to compare numbers because it does not work that way. We can speculate a lot and attrackt answers but in real we won't be able to answer this above and beyond what was already covered in at least 2 high ranging questions [whats-with-the-integer-cache-inside-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/) and  [is-there-a-difference-between == and is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is) and [...]

Comment: [...]  maybe [why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-== or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differen result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why) for the interning parts that might happen for ints (similar to strings).

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you!