# Python: How many objects were created in variable assignments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found a very strange interview question, at least for me.

If we declare the following variables, how many objects were created?

```
a=300, b=300, c=5, d=5
```

- Can someone please explain this?
- I am not sure to which segment in Python this is related to?
- Is it maybe to memory management in Python?

Comment: They're basically asking if `a` and `b` refer to the same object in memory (along with c and d)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: Alternative duplicate target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 different objects, from the [Python docs (Integer objects)](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

UPDATE:

To answer the question explicitly, there are 3 different objects, but only 2 get created, namely, `a` and `b`. (Thanks to @jpa for pointing this out!)

Comment: 3 different objects, of which only 2 get created.

Comment: @Dejan `a` and `b` are different objects `a is b` will return `False`, whereas `c is d` will return True.

Comment: Yes yes sorry I reversed order. Are they different objects in memory?

Comment: a and b are different objects, c and d are the same object.