# id() for a complex number in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 2j
print(id(a))
```

In this, the `id(a)` returns different value each time I run the program. **What is the reason behind this?**

On the other hand,

```
a = 2
print(id(a))
```

That variation is not seen with the above code where `a = 2` refers to an integer and not complex number.

Comment: python maintains a cahce for some integers but it doesnt do it for complex numbers thats why the behaviour is different, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter

Comment: Small ints are exceptional. Ids being different is the expected behaviour.