# ctype.c_long.from_address returns random value for some inputs

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

See this code:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> x=12345
>>> y=x
>>> ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(x)).value
2
>>> a=2
>>> b=a
>>> ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(a)).value
116
>>>
```

for object x it returned expected output but for "a" it's returning an unexpected result

Answer (score 1):

The "expected value" is refcount of an allocated object.

When you assigned `x`, you allocated a new `int` object.
You took another reference, and were unsurprised to see the refcount increment by 1.

When you assigned `a`, you took a reference on an existing object.
The cPython interpreter pre-created a cache of more than two hundred small integers,
and then modules you `import`ed took references to some of them.
Your example output is just saying there are more than a hundred references extant,
cf [What's with the integer cache maintained by the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter#answer-15172182).

Comment: I know about interning in python but let's say interpreter created an object for integer value "2". Then also in the above case value of refcount should be 2. Why is that 116?

Comment: Several executable statements came before you. More than a hundred of them, and some of them mentioned the literal value `2`. You `import`ed all the code in ctypes, but that's not all that ran prior to your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you are reading a Python int object using the C long format.
You are asking Python to read starting from `id(a)` which is an address holding an object of int in Python. Starting from this address you are asking Python to read data as C long which is binary bits in two's complement.