# Why does python point two variables to a same memory address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-address

I declared two variables in Python 3 and tried printing their memory addresses as:

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 1
print(hex(id(num1)))
print(hex(id(num2)))
```

turns out that both the **addresses are the same**.
Why is it so unlike C and C++ where every variable has a unique memory address.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a dup because this particular example is a bit of a special case (in the reference CPython implementation at least). But there's more to it actually - Python's variables are totally different from C/C++ ones, they are not symbolic names for memory locations, but key=>value pairs where the key is the name and the value the object the name is bound to. This is very clearly explained in [this excellent article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) that you definitly want to read.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172182/8733066

The python interpreter doesn't need tho save the value 1 multiple times because int is immutable. So all variables with the value four point to the same memory location.

Answer (score -4):

Because that's how Python works.  Everything is an object.  Every number is an object.  Every different string is an object.  `True` and `False` are objects.

Comment: This doesn't explain why two instances of an integer sometimes are the same object and sometimes not.

Comment: OP didn't ask that.

Comment: please re-read the question - the op very clearly asks why two variables point to the same address.