# "is" comparison of numbers

Tags: python

I was given a Python test and one of the questions was: what should be passed to the following function, so that it will return `True`?

```
def fun(x):
    if x + 1 is 1 + x:
        return False
    if x + 2 is not 2 + x:
        return False
    return True
```

In my opinion this doesn't make much sense but I just would like to know the right answer (if such answer exists).

Comment: Without cooking up my own class which implements addition in a weird way, I don't see how this could work.  You've got me curious.

Comment: Cpython cache integers, which means that some share identity. When you have numbers that are bigger than this range, they'll be newly created and thus have different id's. Don't remember the exact range though

Comment: If you're interested in more weird behaviour like this, check out [pywat](https://github.com/cosmologicon/pywat)

Comment: Since cpython caches -5 to 256 I can be lazy and have python figure it out: `[i for i in range(-10, 300) if fun(i)]`

Comment: See also [What's with the integer cache maintained by the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has to do with how python caches small numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48120163/13003236

Typically, `is` is used to check if two variables are the same object instead of if they have the same value. However, because of how python caches small numbers, calling `is` on numbers from -5 to 256 has the same effect as comparing them. So, this function returns true if `x + 1` is less than -5, but `x + 2` is greater than or equal to -5. That means that passing -7 into this function will cause it to succeed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. -6 is -6 returns true with Python 3.8.5

Comment: @Trilarion try assigning the values to separate variables

Comment: @Trilarion if you did `-6 is -6`, that's different because python interned that number for the compilation unit. It would be equally true for -600000.

Comment: That worked. x is x returns true, whatever x is. 1+x is 1+x does not.

Comment: @SimonShkolnik - As long as the assignments were in the same .py file, they would still have the same id.

Comment: @SimonShkolnik , thank you very much for explanation.
Indeed, I forgot about caching of -5 to 256.
So this example sort of proves statement: "do not use is to compare integers" in the link that you provided.