# python is operator in ide and command line different results

Tags: python

```
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> y = (1, 2)
>>> x is y
```

when I run this code in IDE it returns True but in cmd it returns False. so why is that so?

Comment: Surely, you want `==`, not `is`. You could print  `id(x)` and `id(y)` to double-check

Comment: That's not what's being asked, OP is basically asking why `id(x) != id(y)` in "cmd" but equal in their IDE.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Is that Pycharm?

Comment: Whether or not `(1,2)` produces a distinct object each time it is used, or simply returns the same reference to a single object, is implementation-defined.

Comment: You're doing something that *has no guaranteed result*.  This is like asking why you flipped a coin twice, but it came up heads one time, and tails the other.

Comment: its pycharm yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's with the integer cache maintained by the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter) I'm aware that this claims to be about ints, but the accepted answer answers this regardless of type: *This happens whenever the parser has a chance to analyze where the literals are used, for example when defining a function in the interactive interpreter*

Comment: @jasonharper Not really, as the result is (probably) going to be reproducible within a given implementation.

Comment: For example, try in the CMD to do it as `x = (1, 2) ; y = (1, 2)` (same line) and now it will produce `True`

Comment: https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-how-not-to-use-is-operator