# Python '==' operator gives wrong result

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, operators, deep-copy

I am comparing two elements of a numpy array. The memory address obtained by `id()` function for both elements are different. Also the `is` operator gives out that the two elements are not same.

However if I compare memory address of the two array elements using `==` operator it gives out that the two elements are same.

I am not able to understand how the `==` operator gives output as `True` when the two memory address are different.

Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(8)
newarray = a[np.array([3,4,2])]

print("Initial array : ", a)
print("New array : ", newarray)

# comparison of two element using 'is' operator
print("\ncomparison using is operator : ",a[3] is newarray[0])

# comparison of memory address of two element using '==' operator
print("comparison using == opertor : ", id(a[3]) == id(newarray[0]))

# memory address of both elements of array
print("\nMemory address of a : ", id(a[3]))
print("Memory address of newarray : ", id(newarray[0]))
```

Output:

Initial array :  `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`
New array :  `[3 4 2]`

comparison using `is` operator :  `False`
comparison using `==` operator :  `True`

Memory address of a :  `2807046101296`
Memory address of newarray :  `2808566470576`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to a combination of [Python's integer caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter) and obscure implemetation details of `numpy`.

If you slightly change the code you will see that the `id`s are not consistent during the flow of the code, but they are actually the same on each line:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(8)
newarray = a[np.array([3,4,2])]
print(id(a[3]), id(newarray[0]))
print(id(a[3]), id(newarray[0]))
```

outputs

```
276651376 276651376
20168608 20168608
```

Answer (score 1):

A numpy array does not store references to objects like a list (unless it is object `dtype`).  It has a 1d databuffer with the numeric values, which it may access in various ways.

```
In [17]: a = np.arange(8)
    ...: newarray = a[np.array([3,4,2])]
In [18]: a
Out[18]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
In [21]: newarray
Out[21]: array([3, 4, 2])
```

`newarray`, produced with advanced indexing is not a `view`.  It has its own databuffer and values.

Let's 'unbox' elements of these arrays, assigning them to variables.

```
In [22]: x = a[3]; y = newarray[0]
In [23]: x
Out[23]: 3
In [24]: y
Out[24]: 3
In [25]: id(x),id(y)
Out[25]: (139768142922768, 139768142925584)
```

`id` are different (the assignment prevents the possibly confusing recycling of ids).

`id` are different, so `is` is `False`:

```
In [26]: x is y
Out[26]: False
```

but values are the same (by == test)

```
In [27]: x == y
Out[27]: True
```

Another 'unboxing', different id:

```
In [28]: w = a[3]
In [29]: w
Out[29]: 3
In [30]: id(w)
Out[30]: 139768133495504
```

These integers are actually `np.int64` objects.  Python does 'cache' small integers, but that does not apply  here.

```
In [33]: type(x)
Out[33]: numpy.int64
```

Where can see "where" the arrays store their data:

```
In [31]: a.__array_interface__['data']
Out[31]: (33696480, False)
In [32]: newarray.__array_interface__['data']
Out[32]: (33838848, False)
```

These are totally different buffers.  If `newarray` was a `view` the buffer pointers would be the same or nearby.

If we don't hang on to the indexed object, ids may be reused:

```
In [34]: id(newarray[0]), id(newarray[0])
Out[34]: (139768133493520, 139768133493520)
```

In general `is` and `id` are not useful when working with `numpy` arrays.