# Why the difference is 320 in the address of two different variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, storage

[image]

I initialised different values for different variables in python as

```
x = 10
y = 20
z = 30
```

when i use `id(x)`, `id(y)`, `id(z)` for finding the respective address of x,y,z i found that all their address are differed by 320.

Why they are differed by 320 and why their address are not continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the results of a CPython optimisation called [small integer cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter).

CPython stores integers between -5 and 256 (inclusive) in a special cache as they are frequently used in user programs. This way the interpreter doesn't have to initialise a new object every time you use a number:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = 10
>>> id(x) == id(y)
True
```

while

```
>>> x = 1000
>>> y = 1000
>>> id(x) == id(y)
False
```

Now, assume that the small integer cache looks like this in memory:

```
[-5, -4, -3, ... , 10, ... 20, ..., 256]
```

Small integers normally take 28 bytes in Python 3, but probably because of some 4 byte overhead, each number above takes up exactly 32 bytes:

```
>>> id(1) - id(0)
32
```

When you do

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = 20
```

You actually assign memory locations of `10` and `20` in the small integer cache to the variables `x` and `y`, respectively. That's why you are seeing a difference of 320 bytes (32 * 10) between them.

Note that this behaviour is only guaranteed for CPython. Other Python interpreters may not have a small integer cache, or they might implement the `id()` function differently.