# When a value of a sliced list "copy" is overwritten, the original list does not change. Why? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability

I come from R and am trying to get a better grip on mutability. Below is code, the first two parts of which I think I understand (see comments). I do not understand the third part.

```
#1. Refering to same instance with two variable names
listOrig = [i for i in range(1001, 1011)]
listCopy = listOrig
listOrig[0]=999
listOrig == listCopy #Returns True, because both variable names actually refer
#to the same instance, ergo still containing the same values
listOrig[0] is listCopy[0] #Same instance 999, the id is also the same as a 
#consequence

#2. Refering to same part of original list through slicing
listSlice = listOrig[0:5] 
listOrig[0] is listSlice[0] #Returns True, analogous to above
a = 999
listOrig[0] == a #True because it's the same value or number
listOrig[0] is a #False because they are different instances with different IDs
  
#3. WHAT I DO NOT UNDERSTAND: changing the sliced copy does not affect the original list
listOrig
listSlice
listSlice[0] = 1001
listOrig[0] is listSlice[0] #Different number, thus also obviously different ID
```

Comment: The slice is a copy of a particular range from the original list. Altering the copy does not alter the original. Because it is a copy.

Comment: But listOrig[0] is listSlice[0] is True, should it not be False if what you say is correct?

Comment: All that shows is that the copy contains some of the same objects that are in the original. Then after you do `listSlice[0] = 1001` it contains something else instead.

Comment: Then I do not understand your answer. What is the relationship between the ids of the lists and the items within? I think my problem lies there. The lists have distinct names, but share the same objects (and thus IDs). Creating a copy without slicing creates a new reference to the same instance. Slicing seems to do the same. But when I change a value of the sliced object, it does not affect the original list, but all other instances are identical in terms of id. Why is that? What is the mechanic behind that? Thanks your help!

Comment: The slice is a new list containing some of the same objects. Those same objects will still have the same id. When you reassign a position in the new list, you're putting a different object in that list, but not in the original list. Because it is a different list.

Comment: I can see what you are saying, as is demonstrated by the code, but my expectation would be that making changes to the sliced list (listSlice) has the same effect on the original list as making changes to an unsliced "copy" reference (listCopy ) to the original list (listOrig).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Your `listCopy` is not a copy at all. It is the same list assigned to a new variable.

Comment: @Vorsprung Not really : / It says "so both new_list and my_list refer to the same list after the assignment." I understand that, but from what I see above, a sliced list behaves differently that an "unsliced" new reference to the same list instance when changes are made to it.

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, do not want to be pedantic. I just don't get it. You are right. listCopy refers to the same instance as listOrig. You also said slicing creates a new list. So does that mean that when I slice, a new list is created, but the objects it contains are actually still the same instances as in listOrig? But then what is the difference? The lists themselves are not referring to the same list instance, but the instances within the different lists are still identical?

Comment: The slice is a new list that contains objects from the original list. Not copies of the objects, the same objects. The list is a new list. The contents are new references to existing objects, not copies.

Comment: Okay, thank you @khelwood! I guess that answers my question! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I am going to post an answer just because I think this is better explained with diagrams.

Suppose you create a list `list_1` containing the numbers 1, 2 and 3.

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
```

[image: list_1]

Then you assign the list to a new variable.

```
list_2 = list_1
```

It is another reference to the same original list.

[image: list_2]

Alternatively, suppose you take a slice of your list.

```
list_3 = list_1[:]
```

It is a new list with references to the same objects.

[image: list_3]

So if you reassign an element in the new list, it does not affect the original.

```
list_3[0] = 4
```

[image: changed list_3]

Comment: Thanks for going through all that effort! Much clearer with the diagram!

Answer (score 0):

As is said in the comments, the slice is a copy of the original list. It currently (when the values are same) refers to same memory address and hence the id (with e.g. id-function) is the same and `listOrig[0] is listCopy[0]` is True.

Below example formulates this: even if you set two different integer variables b and c to be the same value, their ids are same. However, if you change the value of b, the value of c does not change. You can also check `print(id(listSlice), id(listOrig[0:5]))` from your example which shows, that the ids of the slice-variable and the original slice are different

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 2

print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id(c))

print(b is c)
```

The output would be e.g.

```
2770111129904

2770111129936

2770111129936

True
```

Comment: This only holds true for numbers smaller than more or less 600

Comment: strings work like that in Java

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter

Comment: @Spaniel well probably it would "work" for larger int literals as well. But this is just *confusing*, because this is an implementation detail about how the compiler handles immutable literals in the same block of code, it doesn't address the OP's question

Comment: "Below example formulates this: even if you set two different integer variables b and c to be the same value, their ids are same" this is **wrong**