# How to cache values in script mode?

Tags: python-3.x, caching

My code is:

```
x = 1000
y = x + 0
z = 1000

print(x is y, x is z, y is z)
```

In REPL mode I have next result:

```
>>> False False False
```

But if I run script in script mode (like '1.py' for example) I have next result.

```
>>> False True False
```

Similar result in REPL with

```
>>> x = 1000; y = x + 0; z = 1000
>>> print(x is y, x is z, y is z)
False True False
```

I think that lexical analyzer make object optimization by translate my code to bite code. But I can't find desciption this process in documentation or books.

Where can I learn this material?

UPD: I need description in official notes. Like python.org. How to work AST-analizer optimization for example.

UPD2: It is desirable without the need to study the CPython source code in depth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's with the integer cache maintained by the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter)

Comment: @ssp by your link that problem is disscused. I find description in sources like python.org. With description not only by C-code. For AST optimizer I guessed earlier.