# Why is the floating-point variable of the subclass the same memory address as the floating-point variable of the parent class?

Tags: python, class

As shown in the code, a parent class `ClassA` is established, which has a variable `var1`, and a subclass `ClassB` inherits the parent class, which has a variable `var2`. As a result, the addresses of `var1` and `var2` are the same, why is this?

As a result, whether I assign a value to `var1` or `var2`, the value of both is the same. What is the reason for this?

My code is as follows:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1: float = 0


class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()
        self.var2: float = 0
        print(id(self.var1) == id(self.var2))


a = ClassB()
```

The result I get:

```
True
```

My expected result:

```
False
```

---

Tried many times, only this can achieve my goal:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1: float = float('nan')


class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self).__init__()
        self.var2: float = float('nan')
        print(id(self.var1) == id(self.var2))


a = ClassB()
```

```
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to how python handle the memory, for some immutable types such as integer or string there are some values that are "common" and cached by python, then when you try to use the same value some other place the cached value is used making it the same address.

The `0` is part of the integers values that are cached by python, so in your case the addresses are the sames.

And yes your value is an integer even if you declare it as a float, the only thing this do is to check if the value match a float and 0 match a float even if it's an int.

You can verify this with

```py
>>> a:float = 0
>>> a
0
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>>
>>> b:float = 0.0
>>> b
0.0
>>> type(b)
<class 'float'>
>>>
```

For more details I suggest you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172182/11260467)