# Python == vs is ... 256 vs 257

Tags: python, singleton

There is the quite famous post, which states that values from -5 to 256 in Python are singletons and that using `is` as comparison operator will return `True`.

When I tried this:

```
c = 257
d = 257

print(c is d)
True
```

I expected this to be `False`. Currently I use Python 3.10. Did the implementation of how integers are stored change? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Looks like they did

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html

"Each Python subinterpreter now has its own “small integer singletons”: numbers in [-5; 257] range. It is no longer possible to change the number of small integers at build time by overriding NSMALLNEGINTS and NSMALLPOSINTS macros: macros should now be modified manually in pycore_pystate.h header file."





257 here is inclusively, but also looks like it would depend on Python Interpreter

Comment: While there might be an interesting tidbit to be found here, you should never be testing numbers with `is` at all, so this is a practically irrelevant implementation detail at best…

Comment: It **is** False on my interpreter in PY 3.10.4 .. not sure whats different.

Comment: @rv.kvetch: I use PyCharm with Anaconda 3.10, but the using this online editor also returned True: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: Yes, this is correct. running a python script using `python ...py` appears to return `True`, whereas the interpreter returns `False`.

Comment: @rv.kvetch: Whats the difference? Isn´t the interpreter responsible for returning the correct values in a python script?!

Comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172182/476