# Python Importing Same Object via Different Paths - Different Behaviour Between Class Attribute and Primitive

Tags: python, import, path, static-variables

Python 3.10.6

Suppose you have the following files:

```
main.py
setter.py
Folder/shared.py
```

With these contents:

```py
# Folder/shared.py
class Shared:
    i = 0 # something that is used in multiple locations
```

```py
# setter.py
from Folder.shared import Shared
def set_i():
    global Shared
    print("mem in setter: " + hex(id(Shared.i)))
    Shared.i = 2 # set the shared resource
```

```py
# main.py
IMPORT_VIA_PATH = False
if IMPORT_VIA_PATH:
    import sys, os
    pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    shared_path = pwd + '/Folder'
    sys.path.insert(0, shared_path)
    from shared import Shared
else:
    from Folder.shared import Shared
from setter import set_i
set_i()
print(Shared.i)
print("mem in main: " + hex(id(Shared.i)))
```

If `IMPORT_VIA_PATH` is `False`, main prints `2` for `i`'s value, and the memory addresses are different.
If `IMPORT_VIA_PATH` is `True`, main prints `0` for `i`'s value, and the memory addresses are the same.

---

Even more confusingly, if `Shared.i` is replaced with just `i`, throughout:

```py
# Folder/shared.py
i = 0 # something that is used in multiple locations
```

```py
# setter.py
from Folder.shared import i
def set_i():
    global i
    print("mem in setter: " + hex(id(i)))
    i = 2 # set the shared resource
```

```py
# main.py
IMPORT_VIA_PATH = True
if IMPORT_VIA_PATH:
    import sys, os
    pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    shared_path = pwd + '/Folder'
    sys.path.insert(0, shared_path)
    from shared import i
else:
    from Folder.shared import i
from setter import set_i
set_i()
print(i)
print("mem in main: " + hex(id(i)))
```

Then for both `IMPORT_VIA_PATH` `True` or `False`, `i` remains zero and the memory addresses are *the same*. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you import from a different path, i.e. your import statement uses a different module name, then python treats it **as a different module**. In one case, `sys.modules` will contain `"Folder.shared"`, so when you import `shared`, it will check if `"shared"` is in `sys.modules`, not find it, so it doesn't just retrieve the already imported module, and then it imports it as a new module.

There is almost **certainly** no good reason to be doing this to begin with. So you should just not do it.

There are no "primitives" in Python. However, CPython *has an implementation detail* that [small integers are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/whats-with-the-integer-cache-maintained-by-the-interpreter), so that is why the same object is re-used for the integer `0`.

Also, when you do `from module import i`, you are assigning the value of `module.i` to a new variable in the importing module.

So *of course* `i` doesn't change. It's a different variable (possibly referring to the same object)

And calling `set_i` only affects `module.i`, not the `i` that you have in your `main` module.